# parse array elements and assign to object

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array like `["1 apple", "2 watermelon"]` and I want to convert it to object like `{apple: 1, watermelon: 2}`

Here is my code but I think I did something wrong:

```
const object = {}
arr.forEach(a => {
    let key = a.match(/\d+/g)
    let value = a.match(/\D+/g)
    Object.assign(object, {
        key: value
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.map()` and `Object.fromEntries()`

```js
const data = ["1 apple", "2 watermelon"];

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  data.map(function(item) {
    let itemSplit = item.split(" ");
    if( itemSplit.length > 2 ) { // ["1 apple", "2 water melon"]
      return [ itemSplit.shift(), itemSplit.join(" ") ].reverse();
    }
    return itemSplit.reverse();
  })
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Note this stops working for `["1 apple", "2 water melon"]`

Comment: Yes @JvdV thanks for pointing it out ;) will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = ["1 apple", "2 watermelon"];

const object = {}
arr.forEach(a => {
    let key = a.match(/\d+/g)
    let value = a.match(/\D+/g)
    Object.assign(object, {
        [value[0]]: key[0]
    })
})

console.log(object)
```

value is an array, you need to specify an index to the element inside, also key in this case is a variable and you have to use the [] syntax when defining an object key from a variable.

This isn't however the best solution to do this job.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `g` flag for your regex, it returns an array of matches, so you can get the first match by using `[0]`. For assigning one key, you don't need `Object.assign`:

```js
const arr = ["1 apple", "2 watermelon"];
const object = {};

arr.forEach(a => {
    let value = a.match(/\d+/g)[0];
    let key = a.match(/\D+/g)[0];
    object[key] = value;
});
```

This still has the issue of the leading space being in the string, so you could say `value = a.match(/\D+/g)[0].substr(1);`, or if you're guaranteed to have the words separated by a space you could just split on space:

```js
const arr = ["1 apple", "2 watermelon"];
const object = {};

arr.forEach(a => {
    const [value, ...keys] = a.split(" ");
    object[keys.join(" ")] = value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr=["1 apple", "2 watermelon"];
const object = {}
arr.forEach(item => {
    const [val,key]=item.split(' ');
    object[key]=Number(val,10);
});
console.log(object);
```

Use the split function to split the string at white space. Use Array de-structuring to capture the constituent parts (i.e in first iteration `item.split(' ')` will return `['1','apple']` and subsequently val is assigned `'1'` and key `'watermelon'`). Use the Number function to convert the string into an integer (the optional parameter is base, here it is 10).